# Issue installing BuildTools using Git

Tags: java, git, maven

Trying to download something called BuildTools, link found slightly down the page [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/#1-12-2). My issue is that, following their tutorial, I open git (the program that allows me to access to my files via a terminal) and ran the command `Java -jar BuildTools.jar`, as requested by the website. Install ends up almost perfectly fine, but then fails right near the end. I've looked at the error message but I can't seem to make heads or tails of it. Does anyone else understand?

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:24 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-06T20:31:54+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.1.0:shade (default) on project bukkit: Error creating shaded jar: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running command, return status !=0: [sh, C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Programming Stuff\BuildTools\apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn, clean, install]
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.runProcess0(Builder.java:639)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.runProcess(Builder.java:597)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.main(Builder.java:462)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:29)
```

I've looked at the things it suggested but I honestly don't quite understand them either. Anyone able to help me out?

Many thanks,
Cookie

EDIT: The bit that comes right before BUILD FAILURE is:

```
Results :

Tests run: 924, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ bukkit ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Programming Stuff\BuildTools\Bukkit\target\bukkit-1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:3.1.0:shade (default) @ bukkit ---
[INFO] Including commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.guava:guava:jar:21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Comment: The _BuildTools.jar_ is using Apache Maven to build something for you via Maven command `mvn clean install`. During the build process, there's a failure when executing goal of `maven-shade-plugin`. Could you show the log before "BUILD FAILURE"?

Comment: Try your build with the most recent version of maven-shade-plugin (3.1.1) there is an improvement for the error message to show the jar file which corrupted..